# Calling viewDidLoad in another controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement a "forward message" feature in my chat app. So, when I click on the button "forward" in my chatVC the popover VC appears with the users that are on my friends list.

[image]

The question is, can I call my chatVC viewDidLoad to refresh the user information? (Otherwise, the user information would be the same as it was before clicking the "forward" button.)
Here's my code where `delegate` is my chatVC:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let friend = friendsList[indexPath.row]
   delegate?.friendProfileImage = friend.profileImage
   delegate?.friendName = friend.name
   delegate?.friendId = friend.id
   delegate?.friendIsOnline = friend.isOnline
   delegate?.friendLastLogin = friend.lastLogin
   delegate?.forwardedMessage = true
   delegate?.messages = []
   delegate?.collectionView.reloadData()
   delegate?.loadNewMessages = false
   delegate?.viewDidLoad()
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Or maybe there is a better way to handle the reload?

Comment: Put the relevant reload code into a separate function. Thats the whole magic. You should call exactly one function on the delegate `didSelectFriend` and pass the instance there.

Comment: You should never call `viewDidLoad` directly, especially not after the view has already been loaded.  Why don't you call some other method on your delegate to update the view?  You should probably have a single method in your delegate `didSelectRecipient(friend: Friend)` rather than updating all of those properties and calling `reloadData` directly - All of that detail should be hidden from the pop up vc

Comment: Consider creating a struct (or class) that holds all the information you want to pass to the chatVC.  Build an instance and set it as a variable in your delegate.  The delegate can then implement `didset` for that variable to refresh whatever is needed.

Comment: @Paulw11 it's not recommended and it's not wrong also it's designated to be called by the system after it loads your view and explicitly calling it after vc appears  won't trigger other subsequent vc's methods so after load it behaves like any other developer created function

Comment: I meant that you shouldn't call it after the system has called it for you; i.e. it should only be called once and that one time by the system.  It isn't forbidden, but there is no reason to do so, as you yourself explained.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Thank y'all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule you should try and loosely couple independent classes as much as possible.  That is one of the purposes of a delegation pattern - Class "A" can inform a delegate that something has happened and provide some data.  Class A doesn't need to know (and shouldn't know) anything more about the delegate object, other than it implements the delegate method.

Your current code is tightly coupled; you are updating properties on the delegate object and reloading a collection view.

Your delegation pattern should look something like this:

```
protocol FriendSelectionDelegate {
    func didSelectRecipient(friend: Friend)
}
```

Then in your pop up view controller all you need is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let friend = friendsList[indexPath.row]
   delegate?.didSelectRecipient(friend: friend)
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in your `ChatVC`:

```
extension ChatVC: FriendSelectionDelegate {
    func didSelectRecipient(friend: Friend) {
        self.friendProfileImage = friend.profileImage
        self.friendName = friend.name
        self.friendId = friend.id
        self.friendIsOnline = friend.isOnline
        self.friendLastLogin = friend.lastLogin
        self.forwardedMessage = true
        self.messages = []
        self.loadNewMessages = false
        self.updateView()
    }
}
```

The `updateView` function performs whatever operations are required to update the views.  You can call that same function in your `viewDidLoad` to set the initial state of the views

As a further improvement, consider whether you need all of those individual properties (`friendName`, `friendId` etc).  Can you just store a single property, `var selectedFriend: Friend` or something and access the properties from that `Friend`.  You can then use a `didSet` on that `selectedFriend` property to call your `updateView` function.

Answer (score 2):

You need put the code in a function that you call from `viewDidLoad` and your delegate